# run loop to generate values that increment intermittently in R

Tags: r, loops

I am trying to label a sequence for contiguity.
The values are already sorted. Now if the values in Tdiff are <400, its part of sequence "n". If the value of Tdiff suddenly changes to something >=400, it becomes part of a new sequence, say "n+1".

The # of rows is humongous... 29.5million. I am trying the code below:

```
    init<-1
    data$seq<-rep(0,29563983)
    for(i in 1:29563983)
    {
        if (data$Tdiff[i]<400)
        {
            data$seq[i]<-init
        } else {
           init<-init+1
           data$seq[i]<-init
        }
    }
```

This is already through a 10-h run. I believe this is still on and is not stuck somewhere.

Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this do what you want?

```
data$seq = cumsum(data$Tdiff >= 400)+1;
```

Comment: ` + 1` could be ` + init`, given the OP's method.

Comment: Dear @user2977721, it is customary on this website to upvote and accept an answer if you like it.